# Difference between quantum Ising model and dipole-dipole model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

It seems to me that the Ising Hamiltonian and the dipole interaction Hamiltonian are very similar to each other. What's the difference between the two? My understanding is the Ising model can be seen as nearest neighbor interaction, but the dipole interaction is more generalized?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct in seeing this similarity. The Ising problem is often posed with this comparison in mind, but the feature of the Ising model that sets it apart is the discretization of the dipole moment. The Ising model is defined such that the dipole moment is either aligned or anti-aligned (as is the case in a spin system). So, whereas in a classical dipole-dipole interaction, the dipole moment can point in any direction, in the Ising model, the dipole moment can only point up or down.

Answer (score 0):

The quantum ising model is quantum (go figure), while the dipole hamiltonian is classical.

For the quantum model, one thing that this means is that the state space is much bigger. For a two-site quantum Ising hamiltonian, you might represent the states as some linear combination of $|\uparrow, \uparrow \rangle, |\downarrow, \uparrow \rangle, |\uparrow, \downarrow \rangle, |\downarrow, \downarrow \rangle$:

$|\Psi\rangle = \sum_{a = \uparrow, \downarrow}\sum_{b = \uparrow, \downarrow}C_{a,b}|a,b\rangle$, where $C_{a,b} \in \mathbb{C}$

In comparison, the state space for the classical dipole hamiltonian is simply:

$|\Psi\rangle \in |1,\theta,\phi\rangle + |2,\theta,\phi\rangle;  \theta, \phi \in \mathbb{R} $

(not sure if my notation is very good there)

From both state spaces, you can define linear mappings and energies and determine the time evolution and stationary states of the system.

If you are interested: More formally, a qubit is described by the SU(2) Lie group while the classical system would be described by SO(3). Wikipedia has a good section on this.